# me aparece Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: php, html, web, undefined

tengo estos dos archivo, el arachivo html y el php pero al ejecutarlo me marcar
Notice: Undefined index: nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\estructuras\saludos.php on line 8
Notice: Undefined index: pass in C:\xampp\htdocs\estructuras\saludos.php on line 9

alguien me podría ayudar a solucionarlo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Ejemplo básico de If </title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="saludos.php" method="get">

¿Quién eres?<br />
<input type="text" name="nombre" /><br />
¿Y tu Contraseña?<br />
<input type="text" name="pass" />

<input type="submit" name="reset" value=" Enviar " />
</form>
</body>
</html>  

este es el archivo .php>

<html>
<head>
<title> Ejemplo básico de If </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Página de bienvenida</h1>
<?php // Empieza el código php

if ($nombre=="Coder" and $pass =="foros") {
// Si el nombre es Coder y la contraseña foros
echo(" Hombre $nombre! Ya estás cotilleando por aquí otra vez!"); // saludo especial

}else {

echo("ahhhhhhhhhhh como no te sabes el nombre y la contraseña, no puedes pasar"); // saludo para los demás
}
?>
</body>
</html>


pero al ejecutarlo me marca este error
Notice: Undefined index: nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\estructuras\saludos.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: pass in C:\xampp\htdocs\estructuras\saludos.php on line 9
ahhhhhhhhhhh como no te sabes el nombre y la contraseña, no puedes pasar
```

Comment: Hola. te hace falta leer los datos enviados: `$nombre= isset($_POST["nombre"]) ? $_POST["nombre"] : '';` y para el password `$pass = isset($_POST["pass"]) ? $_POST["pass"] : '';` para que tengas algo a validar. el error proviene de que las variables no están asignadas. **Nota**: El metodo en form debe ser post para enviar ese tipo de datos **Nunca uses GET para enviar información sensible** queda visible en la dirección del llamado.

Comment: En la indicación usé la superglobal $_POST porque asumo que al corregir **cambiarás el método get por post**